# Tinymce customize toobar with custom plugin

Tags: tinymce, toolbar

I am using Tinymce Version: 4.6.5 and i have a custom plugin added.

But i would like to know if it is possible to add custom plugin to 'insert' toolbar?

[Please see screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xzFg.png)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: anyone have any idea on above?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page for creating a custom plugin shows how to make a menu item:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/

Specifically https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/#exampleplugin includes code that shows how to do this ... look at the code that starts:

```
 // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
 editor.addMenuItem('example', {
```

**EDIT:**  If you want to add something to the `Insert` menu look at the source code for any plugin that is already doing that (e.g. Link).  From that plugin you will see code like this:

```
editor.addMenuItem('link', {
    icon: 'link',
    text: 'Link',
    shortcut: 'Meta+K',
    onclick: Actions.openDialog(editor),
    stateSelector: 'a[href]',
    context: 'insert',
    prependToContext: true
  });
```

Note the `context` setting - this is what places the item on a specific menu.

Comment: Hi @Michael,

Thanks for your response. But actually i know how to add the custom plugin to toolbar.

But what i need is i want to add the custom plugin under the Plus (+) dropdown.

See my screen shot from main post.